# React/Next-js : Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id'), but the object is clearly not empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am having an issue with a `Next-js` `React` checkbox list snippet after extracting it into the sandbox.

whenever I clicked the checkbox, I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

which originated from line `264`:
`setCheckedThread(prev => new Set(prev.add(pageData.currentThreads[index].id)));`

but at the top of the `index.js` I have defined the static `JSON`

and in `useEffect()` I update the `pageData` state with:

```
        setPageData({
            currentPage:    threadsDataJSON.threads.current_page,
            currentThreads:  threadsDataJSON.threads.data,
            totalPages:     totalPages,
            totalThreads:    threadsDataJSON.threads.total,
        });
```

so why when I clicked the `checkbox` it throws the error?

my sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-goldberg-vfu0ve?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `useEffect` on line 280 only triggers once you've checked a box (for some reason), so until you trigger that `useEffect`, `pageData.currentThreads` remains empty, which is where the error you're running into comes from.

I'd suggest moving all the state initialization from the `useEffect` into the `useState` call itself. E.g.

```js
// Bad
const [something, setSomething] = useState(/* fake initial state */);

useEffect(() => {
  setSomething(/* real initial state */)
}, []);

// Good
const [something, setSomething] = useState(/* real initial state */);
```

[Here's a fork of your sandbox with this fix.](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mcnulty-s3k188?file=/pages/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because in `Home` you've created the `handleOnChange` function which is passed to the `List` component that is then passed to the memoized `Item` component. The `Item` component is kept the same across renders (and not rerendered) if the below function that you've written returns true:

```js
function itemPropsAreEqual(prevItem, nextItem) {
  return (
    prevItem.index === nextItem.index &&
    prevItem.thread === nextItem.thread &&
    prevItem.checked === nextItem.checked
  );
}
```

This means that the `Item` component holds the first initial version of `handleOnChange` function that was created when `Home` first rendered. This version of `hanldeOnChange` only knows about the initial state of `pageData` as it has a closure over the initial `pageData` state, which is not the most up-to-date state value. You can either not memoize your `Item` component, or you can change your `itemPropsAreEqual` so that `Item` is rerendered when your `props.handleOnChange` changes:

```js
function itemPropsAreEqual(prevItem, nextItem) {
  return (
    prevItem.index === nextItem.index &&
    prevItem.thread === nextItem.thread &&
    prevItem.checked === nextItem.checked &&
    prevItem.handleOnChange === nextItem.handleOnChange // also rerender if `handleOnChange` changes.
  );
}
```

At this point you're checking every prop passed to `Item` in the comparison function, so you don't need it anymore and can just use `React.memo(Item)`. However, either changing `itemPropsAreEqual` alone or removing `itemPropsAreEqual` from the `React.memo()` call now defeats the purpose of memoizing your `Item` component as `handleOnChange` gets recreated *every time* `Home` rerenders (ie: gets called). This means the above check with the new comparison function will always return `false`, causing `Item` to rerender each time the parent `Home` component rerenders. To manage that, you can memoize `handleOnChange` in the `Home` component by wrapping it in a `useCallback()` hook, and passing through the dependencies that it uses:

```js
const handleOnChange = useCallback(
    (iindex, id) => {
      ... your code in handleOnChange function ...
    }
, [checkedState, pageData]); // dependencies for when a "new" version of `handleOnChange` should be created
```

This way, a new `handleOnChange` reference is only created when needed, causing your `Item` component to rerender to use the new up-to-date `handleOnChange` function. There is also the `useEvent()` hook which is an experimental API feature that you could look at using instead of `useCallback()` (that way `Item` doesn't need to rerender to deal with `handleOnChange`), but that isn't available yet as of writing this (you could use it as a custom hook for the time being though by [creating a shim or using alternative solutions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-read-an-often-changing-value-from-usecallback)).

See working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-wright-n30uyo?file=/pages/index.js).

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply, I am new to `memo` and `callbacks`, still not entirely sure how to se them correctly, I have updated the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-goldberg-vfu0ve?file=/pages/index.js but now it seems to be causing a rerender loop :(

Comment: Hi @yeln, you're using `useMemo()` and not `useCallback()` as shown above.

Comment: @yeln Did using `useCallback()` work?

Comment: hi, yes it works well, but everytime I `uncheck` / `checked` a `checkbox`, the whole list of checkbox seems to re-render instead of just the one I clicked in `react chrome devtools`: https://prnt.sc/xC6S-ieCglpp

Comment: is this normal for the checkboxes?

Comment: @yeln that's generally how memoized components work, when their props change then the checkbox will rerender. You need your checkboxes to rerender when the  `handleOnChange` changes, otherwise they'll refer to an old version of that function that has access to the wrong state values. You can, however, look into using the `useEvent()` hook which I've linked to (instead of useCallback), that way your checkboxes won't rerender. You can use [this](https://github.com/Volune/use-event-callback) example also.

Comment: I see, anyway to make only the clicked single checkbox component rerender instead of all of the checkboxes? all the checkboxes rerenders when I clicked only one to change its state, is it because I stored all of their states in a single array?

Comment: @yeln Not that I can think of, besides using something like `useEvent()`. The problem is, the `handleOnChange` function needs to be linked to each of your functions. Since you don't know which checkbox that will be click on, you need to ensure that each checkbox has the most up-to-date `handleOnChange` function so that if it does get clicked, it's able to call the most up-to-date version of `handleOnChange` which has access to the latest state values.